# How to attach pdf from url using NodeJs (sendgird)

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I want to attach url to Email I used some solutions such as getting pdf url by request or read it as file but it didn't work.

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

var array = [],
    temp = [];

array.push('https://www.antennahouse.com/XSLsample/pdf/sample-
link_1.pdf');

array.push('https://www.antennahouse.com/XSLsample/pdf/sample-
link_1.pdf');

array.forEach(function(data) {
   temp.push({
      path: data,
      filename: 'hello.pdf'
  });

  const msg = {
    to: 'example@example.com',
    from: 'example@example.com',
    subject: 'Test',
    text: 'this is test',
    html: '<strong>Hello World</strong>',
    attachments: temp,
  };

  if ( temp.length == array.length )
      sgMail.send(msg);
  });
```

Comment: According to [docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html), It seems what you want (attach url) is not supported. (take a look at `attachments` section).
you may download the file and attach using `content` property.

Comment: if you need help about downloading the file and attaching it's content, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

This is working solution for me. you can use request npm module to read your pdf file from any source but dont miss { encoding: null }.

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
var request = require('request');
request.get('https://someurl/output.pdf',{ encoding: null },(err,res) => {
  console.log(res);
  var base64File = new Buffer(res.body).toString('base64');

  sgMail.setApiKey('yourSendgridApiKey');
  const msg = {
    to: 'to@mail.com',
    from: 'from@mail.com',
    subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
    text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
    attachments: [
      {
        content: base64File,
        filename: 'some.pdf',
        ContentType: 'application/pdf',
        disposition: 'attachment',
        contentId: 'mytext'
      },
    ]
  }
  sgMail.send(msg, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('error', error)
    } else {
      console.log('successfully sent email' + data);
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
const pdf2base64 = require('pdf-to-base64'); 
sgMail.setApiKey(apiKey); 
const body = await sgMail.send({
      to: email,
      from,
      subject: "subject",
      html: "hello welcome",
      ...(
        attachments && attachments.length && {
          attachments:attachments.map(attachment=>({
            content: attachment,
            filename: "attachment.pdf",
            type: "application/pdf",
            disposition: "attachment"
          }))
        }
      )
    });
     return body;
```

Answer (score -1):

We have example from [sendgird github](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/use-cases/attachments.md). Noted: **content must be string base64 encoded**

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'recipient@example.org',
  from: 'sender@example.org',
  subject: 'Hello attachment',
  html: '<p>Here’s an attachment for you!</p>',
  attachments: [
    {
      content: 'Some base 64 encoded attachment content',
      filename: 'some-attachment.pdf',
      type: 'application/pdf',
      disposition: 'attachment',
      contentId: 'mytext'
    },
  ],
};
```